# Flutter (ChromeSafariBrowser._throwIsAlreadyOpened error)

Tags: flutter, browser, inappbrowser

I'm using a library called flutter_inappbrowser 1.2.1. With the help of this library i'm opening a browser and it work's well at first time, but after that if we try to open the browser again, it will throw error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: [Error: Cannot open https://www.abcd.com/xyzal.html! The browser is already opened.]

The code used for the action is provided below.

```
Center(
child: InkWell(
onTap: () {
chromeSafariBrowser
    .open(url, options: {
"addShareButton": true,
"toolbarBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
"dismissButtonStyle": 1,
"preferredBarTintColor": "#FFFFFF",
"instantAppsEnabled": false
}, optionsFallback: {
"toolbarTopBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
"closeButtonCaption": "Close"
});
},
child: Text(
'Read More...',
style: TextStyle(
color: Color(0xFF38969A),
fontSize: 16.0,
decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
))


class MyInAppBrowser extends InAppBrowser {
  @override
  Future onLoadStart(String url) async {
    print("\n\nStarted $url\n\n");
  }

  @override
  Future onLoadStop(String url) async {
    print("\n\nStopped $url\n\n");
  }

  @override
  void onLoadError(String url, int code, String message) {
    print("\n\nCan't load $url.. Error: $message\n\n");
  }

  @override
  void onExit() {
    print("\n\nBrowser closed!\n\n");
  }
}

MyInAppBrowser inAppBrowserFallback = new MyInAppBrowser();

class MyChromeSafariBrowser extends ChromeSafariBrowser {
  MyChromeSafariBrowser(browserFallback) : super(browserFallback);

  @override
  void onOpened() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser opened");
  }

  @override
  void onLoaded() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser loaded");
  }

  @override
  void onClosed() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser closed");
  }
}

MyChromeSafariBrowser chromeSafariBrowser =
    new MyChromeSafariBrowser(inAppBrowserFallback);
```

Any help will be appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, posting it here as it may help someone in future.

Solution is that instead of calling **chromeSafariBrowser.open(...)** directly call  **MyChromeSafariBrowser(inAppBrowserFallback).open(...)**. New instance will be created and all will work smoothly. Don't know whether it is the proper solution or not.

Eg:

```
onTap: ()  {
MyChromeSafariBrowser(inAppBrowserFallback)
    .open(newsData.url, options: {
"addShareButton": true,
"toolbarBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
"dismissButtonStyle": 1,
"preferredBarTintColor": "#FFFFFF",
"instantAppsEnabled": false
}, optionsFallback: {
"toolbarTopBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
"closeButtonCaption": "Close"
});
},
```

Answer (score 0):

in your on onTap you can check if the browser is hidden ( opened ) then show it instead of open it:

```dart
onTap: () async {

if (chromeSafariBrowser.isOpened()) {
await chromeSafariBrowser.show();
return;
}

await chromeSafariBrowser
    .open(url, options: {
            "addShareButton": true,
            "toolbarBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "dismissButtonStyle": 1,
            "preferredBarTintColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "instantAppsEnabled": false
    }, optionsFallback: {
        "toolbarTopBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "closeButtonCaption": "Close"
   });
```

or if you want reopen it instead of showing it again

```dart
onTap: () async {

if (chromeSafariBrowser.isOpened()) 
    await chromeSafariBrowser.close();
await chromeSafariBrowser
    .open(url, options: {
            "addShareButton": true,
            "toolbarBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "dismissButtonStyle": 1,
            "preferredBarTintColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "instantAppsEnabled": false
    }, optionsFallback: {
        "toolbarTopBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "closeButtonCaption": "Close"
   });
```

Comment: Hi @Shandevs, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it's not working out. Same error coming up.

Comment: @SachinVarma try removing the chromeSafariBrowser.isOpened() ( and put open chromeSafariBrowser.close() in a try catch block )